# As below specs Linux OS can be Install? all driveres will be availabel releted to hardware?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, sound, system-installation, webcam

```
OS
Operating system    FreeDOS
Processor
Processor   Intel® Core™ i5-4210U with Intel HD Graphics 4400 (1.7 GHz, 3 MB cache, 2 cores)
MEMORY
Memory, standard    4 GB 1600 MHz DDR3L SDRAM (1 x 4 GB)
STORAGE
Hard drive description  1 TB 5400 rpm SATA
OPTICAL DISK DRIVE
Optical drive   SuperMulti DVD burner
GRAPHICS
Graphics    NVIDIA GeForce 820M (2 GB DDR3 dedicated)
Display
Display size (diagonal)     15.6"
Display     15.6" diagonal HD BrightView LED-backlit (1366 x 768)
Connectivity
Expansion slots     1 multi-format SD media card reader
Network interface   Integrated 10/100 BASE-T Ethernet LAN
Wireless    802.11b/g/n (1x1) and Bluetooth® 4.0 combo
Ports/Slots
Ports   1 USB 3.0; 2 USB 2.0; 1 HDMI; 1 RJ-45; 1 headphone/microphone combo
INPUT
Webcam  HP TrueVision HD Webcam (front-facing) with integrated digital microphone
Pointing device     Touchpad with multi-touch gesture support
Keyboard    Full-size textured island-style with numeric keypad
Audio
Audio features  Dual speakers
POWER
Power supply type   65 W AC power adapter
Battery type    4-cell (41 WHr) Li-ion
SECURITY
Security management     Kensington MicroSaver lock slot; Power-on password; Accepts third-party security lock devices
MACHINE DIMENSIONS & WEIGHT
Weight  Starting at 2.23 kg
Minimum dimensions (W x D x H)  37.8 x 25.9 x 2.53 cm
```

Answer (score 0):

**Even though you have provided very detailed description of your computer, it is not possible to know for sure if everything will work from the description.**

All the opensource drivers are always included with the default Ubuntu install. If there is a closed-source driver available for your hardware you will get a choice to install the driver it during the Ubuntu installation.

In rare cases, you will have to manually install a closed-source driver.

**What will work**

The CPU, RAM, hard drive, and Graphics.

Note, your laptop has two graphics cards, Intel's built-in and NVIDIA 280M. If this is a NVDIA Optimus system Windows can switch between these two as an when needed without any input from you. Ubuntu (and Linux, in general) does not have this capability yet. You will have to select one, and turn the other off. There are two drivers available for the NVDIA graphics card. You may choose the proprietary one instead of the default opensource one at the time of installation or at any time later.

**What may or may not work**

These things will most probably work, but we don't know for sure with the information provided. Laptop makers use chips by different component manufacturers for these components and may switch from one to another for the same model made in different date. Without knowing the manufacturer, make and model numbers of each components, we can't be sure the following components will work:

- Wireless and bluetooth
- Wired network
- webcam

**What can you do?**

As others have said, you can create a Live USB/DVD for Ubuntu and boot from it without making any changes to your computer. [This will run a full version of Ubuntu directly from the Live USB/DVD.](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/try-ubuntu-before-you-install) When it boots up, you can verify that all your hardware works.

Hope this helps